# How do i fetching the image from the mysql database

Tags: pyqt4, mysql-python

Please give me some image fetching particular code which is help me to fetching the image from mysql database.I already store the image blob data into a database and then fetching it,but only hexadecimal values are fetching and show me.So, i want to know the actual code for fetching the image??

Comment: This may help you [link](http://www.numericalexpert.com/blog/sqlite_blob_time/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use BLOB data type of sql or either you can store path to images to load from DOM

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html